VS Code Python run status
Can the VSCode show status execution in a way PyCharm does?
I run multiple scripts (same with different parameters or different scripts) at a time, with PyCharm there is a small green dot icon 
, that tells me, the script is still executing. Once its done it disappears. In VSCode I have to click through all the scripts and check manualy for execution status.
This is the only thing that is keeping me from switch to VSCode.
VSCode example:

Any help would be appreciated.

I mean- I'm sure (don't quote me on that :P) it's not impossible. In fact- it's probably possible via extension API (FileDecoration and DebugAdapterTracker or something along those lines). If the Python extension isn't doing that, you could raise a feature request issue ticket that they do that. If they say no, you could probably write a separate extension yourself.

Thank you, I am not familiar with the VSCode yet, but this seems doable. I will look into it. We will see what happens later. The python extension is not doing it by itself.
